# The Divider not visible while using Light.DarkActionBar of ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock library to provide Action bar and fragments  support for Android 2.2+ devices.

Previosuly I was using **Theme.Sherlock** as mentioned in several examples. But Now due to some requirements I have changed the theme to **Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar**. Now I think their is some problem with the implementation of this theme. The divider between ActionBar (Title) and tab bar is not visible ?

see following two images

```
1. using Theme.Sherlock
2. using Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar
```

[image: using Theme.Sherlock]

**AND**

[image: using Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar]

1. How do I get that line between Title Bar and Tab bar while using
   Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar ?
2. Can I change the color of line as well as color of ActionBar itself?

Comment: no you cant change the color of a particular line... you need to change the theme...

Comment: ok.. thanks but can you tell me how I can get that default line when using Light theme

Answer (score -2):

You can change the theme from manifest in your application tag :

try this for example.. m not sure it will show the line with desired color but you can choose theme of your choice using cntrl+space

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
```

Comment: I know how to change the theme... please read my question again I want some way to get that blue line when using Light.DarkActionBar theme...